# Why is magnetic attraction field lines when seen with ferrocell reverse that with iron filings?

Tags: electromagnetism

Magnetic attraction seen with ferrocell. The magnetic field pattern is the same as that for repulsion when viewed with iron filings. Why?

[image]

Comment: I recently contributed to a virtual Magnetics conference that explains what you are questioning. Here is a link to the movie- https://youtu.be/-I3HDrR9pts and here is a link to the references- https://ferrocell.us/references/Links%20to%20References%20mmm2021.pdf
I hope my presentation makes the Ferrocell's response to magnetism and light more understandable. ~Timm Vanderelli, Ferrocell USA

Answer (score 1):

I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHTwS6Cxr50) that has both attractive and repulsive set ups on  a ferrocell . They look different, and justify the commentator " field lines or something like them".

The lines you see are the fields interacting with the ferrocell, differently than the orientation of the dipoles, which are what the  iron filings show.

My conclusion is that the ferrocell lines do not show the direct orientation of dipoles that iron filings do, lining up with the field lines, they are possibly a second level magnetic interaction in the cell.

[image: repulsb]

[This is how iron filings show repulsion](https://www.alamy.com/iron-filings-showing-magnetic-force-field-of-a-bar-magnet-image8697946.html)

[image: attract]

And this is how they show attraction lines.

The effects registered in the video must be some optical effect induced by the existence of nano size dipoles which are not visible, possibly difraction.

Comment: Ferrofluid in a ferrocell is just iron filings at a nano scale, tough. One explanation I saw is that the scale of iron filings makes them "one-directional", showing only half of the magnetic field, whereas nano-sized equivalent is bi-directional. This is showing ferrofluid under a microscope, and how the "iron filings" in it align with magnetic lines of force, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0vFWo4BLM8

Comment: In the video you link the speaker at the end is talking of difraction. It is possible that the lines seen in your video, and in the one I linked,  are optical difraction patterns from the intrinsic nano dipoles. a second level effect

Comment: the field pattern for repulsion is the opposite as well from iron filings, https://i.imgur.com/kfdrjMn.jpg

Comment: so it is not field lines that one sees in the cell, some sort of optical effect.

Comment: if the premise that iron filings show field lines is correct, that premise could be false tough and the nano-size "iron filings" could be showing actual field, the other one favoured just because it has been around longer

Comment: so it is not fied lines but "a point inverse field symmetry", not a well known matter. I still think it must be diffraction, the nanolines making a diffraction grating.

Comment: the iron filings are obvious mangetic dipoles, measurable  and following the calculted field from the equations.

Comment: I think what they mean with "inverse field symmetry" is that it is inverse to the models that are based on iron filings. With the nano-scale iron filings you are able to see the Bloch wall within the overall magnetic field, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_wall_(magnetism)

Comment: The iron filings follow the magnetic field lines of the magnetic field equations. Domains discussed in the link above seem to be a different story, not field lines, that follow different equations. I have to say goodnight now.

Comment: and the two alternatives are that either the nano-size iron filings are not showing the magnetic field lines, or, the iron filings are not showing the magnetic field lines. models that have been around a long time tend to be favoured not because of the evidence but because of "status quo bias".

Comment: well, I am all for data trumping theory, but in the case of iron filings theory fits the hypothesis that they are dipoles orienting themselves according to the field. These are theoretical curves: https://d2m3egcl06pis7.cloudfront.net/pub/media/wysiwyg/magnets/27.jpg

Comment: yes fits that theory, conforms to that theory. and, the data from ferrocells either breaks that theory or is something like like optical illusion. it is either one of those.

Answer (score 0):

Pehr is correct. Iron filings are too low resolution to show all of the fine details of the field. The nanoparticles of nickel in the ferrofluid do a much better job at illustrating the point vector of magnetisation because they are simply smaller and shorter and are therefore exposed to more of a point vector of magnetism rather than a sum of point vectors.

A magnetically huge iron filing will orient according to the sum of that magnetic forces at that area in space it occupies which means it will aling in the typically expected fashion. At smaller scales, like with diluted ferrofluid, you can see better detail of the point vector at that location in space.

The lensing effect of the ferrofluid is therefore a more direct and accurate representation of the point vectors that make up the magnetic field.

Arguably, a ferrocell is the highest resolution representation  of a magnetic field that we will ever be able to produce with ferromagnetic particles in a way that is observable to the naked eye.

Edit: also field lines are not the same. They're just huge. Look again in slow motion. You can see the field lines converge as the magnets are placed together and diverge on the repulsion side.